# Google Visualization charts/dashboards failing to fully draw

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm working with Google Visualizations to build a dashboard that will display many different collections of data in chart, time series, and table form (For completeness sake, the html is generated by Python, although I don't think this has anything to do with my problem). I handle the tables myself, and they work fine, and I have yet to implement the charts, although I built slightly different charts for a previous iteration. With that context out the way, my problem comes from the time series: the page successfully displays the filters (i.e. 'Metric'  and 'Category' and associated dropdowns), but not the line graph, and gives the error "One or more participants failed to draw().". An additional, identical, error is displayed each time a filter is selected.

Here is my (anonymized) code, with the associated html:

```
<div class="time" id="conttime"><div id="contlinetime"></div><div id="cont_met"></div><div id="cont_cat"></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});
      function drawVisualization() {var contMetFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId':'cont_met',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Metric',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false,
        'allowNone' : false
      }
    }
  });var contCatFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId':'cont_cat',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Category',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false,
        'allowNone' : false,
      }
    }
  });   var obj = [
    [new Date(2013, 11, 12), 25651, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 11), 25651, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 10), 25651, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 09), 25681, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 08), 25681, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 12), 55, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 11), 55, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 10), 55, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 09), 55, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 08), 55, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 12), 5120, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 11), 5120, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 10), 5120, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 09), 4961, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 08), 4961, 'Sample Metric #1', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 12), 26389, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 11), 26389, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 10), 26389, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 09), 26417, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 08), 26417, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 12), 55, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 11), 55, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 10), 55, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 09), 55, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 08), 55, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 12), 5793, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 11), 5793, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 10), 5793, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 09), 5565, 'Sample Metric #2', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 12), 119398, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 11), 119398, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 10), 119398, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 09), 119505, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 08), 119505, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #1'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 12), 56, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 11), 56, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 10), 56, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 09), 56, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 08), 56, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #2'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 12), 7360, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 11), 7360, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 10), 7360, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 09), 7108, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #3'],
    [new Date(2013, 11, 08), 7108, 'Sample Metric #3', 'Sample Category #3']];
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
         data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Metric');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
         data.addRows(obj);
      var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         chartType: 'LineChart',
         containterId: 'contlinetime',
         'view': {'columns': [0, 1]},
         options: {
             'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '80%'},
             'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
             'curveType': "line",
             'pointSize': 3,
             'legend': {'position': 'none'}}});
    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('conttime')).
    bind([contMetFilter, contCatFilter], lineChart).
    draw(data);
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
```

I've looked through both the stackOverflow and Google Groups archives, and I've found other people who had this problem, though from what I can tell the problems and solutions are different from what I'm facing. Finally, I have yet to really play with the options besides one that seemed like possible solutions to my problem, so I don't particularly care about the readability of these charts at this time, but rather the actual creation of these charts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the line chart's ChartWrapper: `containterId` should not have two t's.  Change it to `containerId` and your code runs properly.